# I have problem implementing residuals function for leastsq optimization of scipy when importing it from another file

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

I have written a code in which functions are called in each other. The working code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import RF

func = RF.roots
# residuals = RF.residuals

def residuals(params, x, y):
    return y - func(params, x)

def estimation(x, y):
    p_guess = [1, 2, 0.5, 0]
    params, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = leastsq(residuals, p_guess, args=(x, y), full_output=True)
    return params

x = np.array([2.78e-03, 3.09e-03, 3.25e-03, 3.38e-03, 3.74e-03, 4.42e-03, 4.45e-03, 4.75e-03, 8.05e-03, 1.03e-02, 1.30e-02])
y = np.array([2.16e+02, 2.50e+02, 3.60e+02, 4.48e+02, 5.60e+02, 8.64e+02, 9.00e+02, 1.00e+03, 2.00e+03, 3.00e+03, 4.00e+03])

FIT_params = estimation(x, y)
print(FIT_params)
```

where RF file is:

```
def roots(params, x):
    a, b, c, d = params
    y = a * (b * x) ** c + d
    return y

def residuals(params, x, y):
    return y - func(params, x)
```

I would like to remove **residuals** function from the main code and use it by calling from **RF** file instead i.e. by activating the code line `residuals = RF.residuals`. By doing so, error `NameError: name 'func' is not defined` will be appeared. I put *func* argument in RF's *residuals* function as `def residuals(func, params, x, y):` which will face to error `TypeError: residuals() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`; It seems the error is related to the *forth argument* of the residuals function in this sample because it will get error for 'func' if the *func* argument be placed after the *y* argument. I couldn't find out the source of the issue, but I guess it must be related to [limitation of arguments in functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html). I would be appreciated if anyone could guide me to understand the error and its solution.
Is it possible to bring *residual* function from the main code to the RF file? How?

Comment: Given your residual function: it may be easier for you to use [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) instead, which deals with `func` directly.

Comment: Thanks @9769953, I agree. I have searched and [find out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464679/difference-between-scipy-optimize-least-squares-and-scipy-optimize-curve-fit) there will not be any differences between these two methods relating to my sample, and I will changed the code for `curve_fit`. But, I am curious about the cause of the problem and how to correct it.

Comment: Certainly a good point, and I think joni answered it correctly below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there's no global variable `func` in your file `RF.py`, hence it can't be found. A simple solution would be to add an additional parameter to your `residuals` function:

```py
# RF.py
def roots(params, x):
    a, b, c, d = params
    y = a * (b * x) ** c + d
    return y

def residuals(params, func, x, y):
    return y - func(params, x)
```

Then, you can use it inside your other file like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from RF import residuals, roots as func

def estimation(func, x, y):
    p_guess = [1, 2, 0.5, 0]
    params, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = leastsq(residuals, p_guess, args=(func, x, y), full_output=True)
    return params

x = np.array([2.78e-03, 3.09e-03, 3.25e-03, 3.38e-03, 3.74e-03, 4.42e-03, 4.45e-03, 4.75e-03, 8.05e-03, 1.03e-02, 1.30e-02])
y = np.array([2.16e+02, 2.50e+02, 3.60e+02, 4.48e+02, 5.60e+02, 8.64e+02, 9.00e+02, 1.00e+03, 2.00e+03, 3.00e+03, 4.00e+03])

FIT_params = estimation(func, x, y)
print(FIT_params)
```